# Nginx and Django - JWT problems

Tags: django, api, nginx, jwt, gunicorn

I'm using Django Rest Framework to create an API. It works great when I run it locally, but when I deploy it to my server I'm having an issue with JWT. When I'm trying to POST new data, I receive an error that says:

"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Of course, I'm passing the Authorization header:

```
authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJK.....
```

On my server, I'm using nginx with the gunicorn. Here's my nginx config:

```
upstream api {
    server unix:/home/bartalamej/api.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.html;

    server_name api.mysite.cz;

    location /v1 {
        rewrite ^/v1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_set_header USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST True;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location /media  {
        alias /home/bartalamej/api/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/bartalamej/api/static;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you know where the token stops? Do you see it sent from the browser in the developer tools? Do you see it accepted by nginx in its logs? Do you see it accepted in Django in the appropriate middleware? Is the passed value correct?

Comment: I can't see anything in nginx logs. I don't know how to check in django accepts my token

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my Django configuration. In my production settings the authentication classes were missing